# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - How to verify the element is loaded/visible at the bottom right corner of the screen?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to the selenium automation and would like to know how can I verify/make sure the element is loaded in the bottom left corner of the screen.

One solution I came across is by finding the x,y coordinate of the nearby element, and then try to find the target element in the proximity. Moreover, I read about `verifyElementPositionLeft` but not sure how to use it because in the new selenium IDE it's not there. (I Believe).

Not looking for exact code, but the different approaches to achieve.

Thanks in Advance. Cheers to the community.

Comment: You can try with isdisplayed(),isenabled() methods in selenium

Comment: @JustinLambert as per my understanding these methods can verify the existence but cant verifies the position of any element. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As another option, consider using the sikuli libraries.
Sikuli is about image automation. It finds a interacts with your baseline images.

Typically, I would say using images is a last resort for functional testing. Things like colour and screen resolution make them flaky and high maintenance objects.

However as an option, for just a checkpoint, it's valid.
You can use selenium to navigate to a location, selenium or javascript to bring scroll into view, then use a *SMALL* image just a bit larger than the element you want to verify. Try and capture parts of the elements around it just enough to make it unique and satisfy your needs but not so much that it becomes flaky.

For example, if i wanted to test the image of stackoverflow was in the top left i'd do this much:
[image: stack logo]
...I'm banking on that little vertical bar being my position anchor.

As it's perfect timing, the sikuli project home page seems to be down, but their [docs are online](http://doc.sikuli.org/)

A premium option is [applitools](https://applitools.com/). They're all about visually testing web pages and the position. They've got lots of capabilities around helping the validation cross-browser to.

[quick update] Applitools offer a free account for 100 checks a month so you can try them out. On the [pricing page](https://applitools.com/pricing/) scroll down to find the free option

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. I will try whatever you have suggested and let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to verify that element is at bottom right of the page then you should compare element's x & y coordinate with page view port height and width.

To collect view port height and width you could use javascriptexecutor and use

```
viewportHeight = window.innerHeight

viewPortWidth = document.body.clientWidth
```